# PHP floor returns two diffent resutl when formula is same?

Tags: php, division, multiplication, floor

```
echo 'For the month of January-2019';
echo'<hr>';
echo $basicValue = floor((250000 / 31) * 31);

echo '<br>';

echo $allowance = (30000 / 31) * 31;
echo '<br>';
echo $house_rent=floor($allowance);
echo'<hr>';
echo 'For the month of February-2019';
echo'<hr>';
echo $basicValue = floor((250000 / 28) * 28);

echo '<br>';

echo $allowance = (30000 / 28) * 28;
echo '<br>';
echo $house_rent=floor($allowance); // This is return 29999 that is wrong???
```

Comment: Read the documentation. `php.net/` + `floor` = [php.net/floor](http://php.net/floor): `Returns the next lowest integer value (as float) by rounding down value if necessary.`

Answer (score 2):

That's because `$allowance` is a float and `floor` is returning an int.

For your expected result I suggest to use `round()` to round the `float` value.

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.round.php

See: https://3v4l.org/skrQC

The output of :

```
echo 'For the month of January-2019';
echo "\n";
echo $basicValue = floor((250000 / 31) * 31);

echo "\n";

echo $allowance = (30000 / 31) * 31;
echo "\n";
var_dump($allowance);
$allowance = intval($allowance);
echo "\n";
var_dump($allowance);
echo "\n";
echo $house_rent=floor($allowance);
echo "\n";
echo 'For the month of February-2019';
echo "\n";
echo $basicValue = floor((250000 / 28) * 28);

echo "\n";

echo $allowance = (30000 / 28) * 28;
echo "\n";
var_dump($allowance);
$allowance = intval($allowance);
echo "\n";
var_dump($allowance);
echo $house_rent=floor($allowance); // This is return 29999 that is wrong???
```

is:

```
For the month of January-2019
250000
30000
float(30000)

int(30000)

30000
For the month of February-2019
250000
30000
float(30000)

int(29999)
29999
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `30000 / 28` is not an integer number and it cannot be represented exactly. A small rounding error occurs. The value represented in the computer is slightly smaller than the exact mathematical value of the expression. When multiplied by `28`, the result is slightly smaller than `30000` and `floor()` does what it is supposed to do: ignores the decimal part and returns only the integral part which is `29999`.

The value of `30000 / 28 * 28` as it is represented in computers is approximately `29999.9999999999963620211929082870`.

Read more about the floating point representation and the problems you may encounter using it: https://floating-point-gui.de/

---

This is not a problem of PHP or of the floating point representation of numbers in computers. It is something that also happens in real life.

We usually consider that `1/3` is `0.333333333333333...` but no matter how many `3` we put after the decimal dot, multiplying it by `3` doesn't produce exactly `1`.